# Is there a way to change the Mathematica front end's title bar description?

Tags: windows, mathematica, title-bar

Is there a way to change the title bar description of Mathematica's Front End?  This would be very useful in differentiating between them when running two instances of the program (e.g. running a long computation in one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a docked cell with the version number in it.  Here's a starting point:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData[
    ToBoxes[NumberForm[$VersionNumber, {2, 1}], StandardForm]], 
   "DockedCells", ShowStringCharacters -> False
   ]]
```

(Note that `$FrontEndSession` won't persist past quitting the front-end.)

**Edit**

Here's a version with an orange background that goes edge-to-edge.  The key option is `CellMargins`:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData[
    ToBoxes[NumberForm[$VersionNumber, {2, 1}], StandardForm]], 
   "DockedCells", ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
   CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Background -> Orange]]
```

Comment: This is very useful, it shows a docked cell on *every* notebook.  I was looking for a way to change the window title of the main Mathematica window, so I could differentiate between taskbar buttons too, but this is already very good.  I'd like to use colour-coding, similar to: `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 DockedCells -> 
  Cell[BoxData[""], "DockedCells", Background -> Orange]]`. How would I make the cell a bit narrower, and completely filled with the colour? (The borders are still white now.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  It was being quite moody:  when I tried my example, sometimes it did have margins, and sometimes it didn't, depending on what I have tried before in the same session.  Now I remember you also used this technique in your SO notifier answer.